# How to disable Javascript when using Selenium by JAVA?

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, firefox, selenium

I'm using selenium for web test by JAVA.
I want to stop JavaScript on Firefox Browser,Google Chrome Browser,IE Browser.

I tried this code on Firefox Browser.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("javascript.enabled", false);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

But it's return this error on second line.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Preference javascript.enabled may not be overridden: frozen value=true, requested value=false
```

How to disable Javascript when using Selenium each Browser?
If you know about this problem,Please help me!

Answer (score 3):

Use [noscript addon for firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/noscript/). *Right click* on the **Add to Firefox** button and *Save link as* that will give you the option to save the `.xpi`. Then, configure the the `Firefox` profiler as follows.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.AddExtension(@"PATH\TO\noScript.xpi");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:8080/");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
 I have to use this program on first time user's PC.
So I can't make noScript.xpi.

Can I make profile before, I start Browser?