# Can't turn off Javascript using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, firefox, selenium

I'm trying to turn off javascript via the profile when opening using Selenium. This has work previously but now I've updated Selenium/Firfox I can't get it to work.

```
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('javascript.enabled', False)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get("http://www.enable-javascript.com/")
```

All other settings seem to change while using profile.set_preference() on other option and `javascript.enabled` exists and is set to True when I look at the Firefox settings about:config. Is it possible Javascript is being set to True after loading the profile or something?

FF version 43.0.3
Selenium version 2.48.0

Any suggestions on why this could be happening?

UPDATE

Adding `profile.add_extension("path/to/noscript_security_suite-2.9.xpi");` to the above code with the downloaded extension as @alecxe suggested fixed the issue.

Comment: A good workaround, if you don't manage to figure it out, is to create a profile with javascript already disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue affects `selenium` starting with 2.46.0, `javascript.enabled` is being ignored:

- [Firefox driver 2.46.0 regression - unable to set to non-js](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/635)

As a workaround, load the `noscript` addon, see:

- [How to disable Javascript when using Selenium by JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667305/how-to-disable-javascript-when-using-selenium-by-java)