# Disable Javascript in Selenium? Noscript doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, java, firefox, selenium, firefox-addon

I am trying to disable javascript in selenium using noscript extension, as suggested here -->[How to disable Javascript when using Selenium by JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667305/how-to-disable-javascript-when-using-selenium-by-java)

But, it looks like it no longer works,
Here is what I have written :

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    File extPath = new File("noscript.xpi");
    profile.addExtension(extPath);
    //profile.setPreference("javascript.enabled", false);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://enable-javascript.com");
```

Even tried it by loading a profile that has javascript disabled, that doesn't seem to work either.

***Code :***

```
    File profileDirectory = new File("Profiles/4hsi6txm.testing");
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(profileDirectory);
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    //
    cap.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
    driver.get("http://enable-javascript.com");
```

I am trying it on `Firefox version-43.0.1` and `selenium version-2.48.2`

Any fix for this ?
Thanks :)